# Position of observer (lat/lon)

Tags: python-3.x, pyephem

I'm playing around with pyephem and jplephem and I can't seem to figure out how to track the path of an observer (or given lat/lon/date) in time with these package. What I would like to do is record the position (x,y,x) over time of a supplied lat/long/date on Earth with respect to the Sun. Imagine the path generated by a tracer on the surface of Earth w.r.t. the Sun.

Is there a way to easily get the position of a point on Earth's surface with respect to Earth's barycenter at a given time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the position of the Earth and the position of the sun from JPLEphem. You can also get the detailed rotation, precession and nutation of the Earth. Now solve for the intersection of your preferred ellipsoid (or geoid) with the Earth-Sun vector at a given time.

Comment: That being said, this question is way too broad for SO. If you have a specific coding question from one of your attempts, I would be glad to help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyEphem library is built atop an astronomy library called `libastro` that, alas, does not provide access to its underlying vectors. And jplephem doesn't know anything about the position of the planets in the Solar System.

But the Skyfield astronomy library, for which jplephem was written, does both. Here is how you would find out the x,y,z position of an Earth location relative to the sun:

```
from skyfield.api import load, Topos

# Let's consider 72 hours starting at midnight UTC on January 2.

duration_hours = 72

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.utc(2018, 1, 2, range(duration_hours))

# Load a planetary ephemeris.

planets = load('de421.bsp')
earth, sun = planets['earth'], planets['sun']

# Print where the US Naval Observatory was each hour relative to the Sun.

usno = Topos('38.9215 N', '77.0669 W', elevation_m=92.0)
result = sun.at(t).observe(earth + usno)
for time, position_au in zip(t, result.position.au.T):
    print(time.utc_jpl(), position_au)
```

The resulting lines look like:

```
A.D. 2018-Jan-04 21:00:00.0000 UT [-0.24130305  0.87456403  0.37915831]
A.D. 2018-Jan-04 22:00:00.0000 UT [-0.2420075   0.87440863  0.37908723]
A.D. 2018-Jan-04 23:00:00.0000 UT [-0.24271409  0.87425296  0.37901595]
```

Here's Skyfield's home page:

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/

Comment: Wow, this works amazingly straightforwardly. Thanks so much, Brandon!